# Cannot resolve type error when using hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I'm getting a "Cannot resolve type" error for the following line of code. I've been doing some googling and saw that this way of defining Type is deprecated but I dont know an alternative way to go about defining this. Any insight would be much appreciated, thanks!

`@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")`